# Using different compilers in same vhdl project

Tags: vhdl, compiler, modelsim

I am currently working on a mips microprocessor for one of my class using modelsim's tools.

I want to be able to work on the same projet whether I'm at home on my windows pc or on the go with my Macbook without having to use a windows virtual machine so I installed ghdl which is a gcc based vhdl compiler/simulator.

I just want to make sure that every vhdl compiler are standardized and can be used on the same project without impact. Is this the case?

Comment: Are you making the project for a specific chip? If so you should use the chip-specific software. For the main FPGA vendors you can find the software for both Windows and Linux, but unfortunately not for Mac. In this case you should use the virtual machine. Or learn the command line tools for this software and work via remote connection to your windows machine.

Comment: I am using an Altera fpga. I don't really have access to the card or the software outside the lab which I can go for like 3 hours a week. So using others compiler allow me to check my syntax and the waveform and when I'm at the lab I simply import my vhdl file in the altera project and recompile it  using Quartus.

Comment: You will probably have troubles (solvable, but still..) with this approach. But there is another catch. Altera's FPGAs have some IP cores (megafunctions) integrated on the chip which can greatly reduce your time and chip resources, and all you have to do is to configure and instantiate them. But it is possible only from their Quartus software.

Comment: gvhdl or ghdl? gvhdl is a front end script to Freehdl and ghdl is a gcc frontend, as well as pretty much completely IEEE Std 1076-1993 compliant. There's an unreleased version of ghdl that will support a lot of -2008 features. See [ghdl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ghdl) tagged questions on Stackoverflow.